# Error when implementing 'ng-multiselect-dropdown' for Angular version 16

Tags: angular, ng-multiselect-dropdown, angular16

I am implementing `ng-multiselect-dropdown` on `Angular 16` project. I have installed the library with command `npm i ng-multiselect-dropdown`

I have imported it in `app.module.ts` file as well.

```
import {NgMultiSelectDropDownModule} from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...,
    NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot()
  ]
```

But when I run the code i get error as below:

```
Error: src/app/app.module.ts:37:12 - error NG6002: 'NgMultiSelectDropDownModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

 37   imports: [
               ~
 38     BrowserModule,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (ng-multiselect-dropdown) which declares NgMultiSelectDropDownModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

`Package.json` file content below

```
{
  "name": "multiselectdropdown",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve": "node ./server.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "@pnp/common": "^1.3.6",
    "@pnp/graph": "^1.3.6",
    "@pnp/logging": "^1.3.6",
    "@pnp/odata": "^1.3.6",
    "@pnp/polyfill-ie11": "^1.0.2",
    "@pnp/sp": "^1.3.6",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.9",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "sp-pnp-js": "^3.0.10",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.1.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "sp-rest-proxy": "^3.3.5",
    "typescript": "~5.0.2"
  }
}
```

Any leads or help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `ng-multiselect-dropdown` library might not support Angular's new Ivy architecture yet. The Angular Compatibility Compiler (ngcc), which provided a way for libraries built for the old View Engine architecture to be compatible with Ivy, was removed in Angular 16.

Comment: Can you suggest any alternative library which would be compatible with Angular 16?

Comment: [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection) and [PrimeNG](https://primeng.org/multiselect) both have a multiselect component available.

Comment: thanks for the information
here the doc : https://angular.io/guide/update-to-version-16#angular-compatibility-compiler-ngcc-has-been-removed

Answer (score 0):

i've tried this and it's work

```
ng update ng-multiselect-dropdown
```

hope that helps  you